# Why is Tomcat complaining about attempting to write too much to a response header?

Tags: java, apache, http, tomcat, http-headers

My service functions as a proxy server that will send GET requests using a proxy, add some info into the header, and return this to the client. But sometimes I get this error when I'm writing the extra headers:

```
org.apache.coyote.http11.HeadersTooLargeException: An attempt was made to write more data to the response headers than there was room available in the buffer. Increase maxHttpHeaderSize on the connector or write less data into the response headers.
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.checkLengthBeforeWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:546)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.write(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:510)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.write(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:427)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.sendHeader(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:393)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.prepareResponse(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1468)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.action(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:764)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.action(Response.java:172)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractOutputBuffer.doWrite(AbstractOutputBuffer.java:185)
at org.apache.coyote.Response.doWrite(Response.java:504)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:383)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:342)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.writeBytes(OutputBuffer.java:413)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.write(OutputBuffer.java:401)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream.write(CoyoteOutputStream.java:91)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:221)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:282)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:125)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:135)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:220)
at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:157)
at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:106)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:106)
at org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(StringHttpMessageConverter.java:40)
at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:179)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:148)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:124)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:69)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:122)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:745)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:686)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:936)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:827)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:812)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I find this strange because the only thing I add into the header is {"proxy_error":"false"}. Did I just happen to send a GET to a website that returned so many headers that I couldn't write another one in? Or am I somehow causing the buffer to get too big by never clearing it (I'm sending thousands of GET requests to random urls, each time I am copying over their headers).

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/hi"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String test(final String url, HttpServletResponse response) {
    CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = sendGetRequest(url);

    response.setHeader(PROXY_ERROR_KEY, "false");

    // Copy the fetched headers
    for (Header header : httpResponse.getAllHeaders()) {
        response.addHeader(header.getName(), header.getValue());
    }
    response.setStatus(httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
    return "hello";
}
```

Comment: You are duplicating all existing headers, no?

Comment: yes, is that the problem? can i do it another way?

Comment: You are duplicating them in place, as far as I can tell.

Comment: is there a way to duplicate them that's not in place? It would be nice if I can make HttpServletResponse response point to CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse, and then I can just add PROXY_ERROR_KEY, false and be done with it, but I am not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me as well, in Jersey. I set a breakpoint on `Exception`, waited for Eclipse to break on it, walked through the stack and parameters and found:

I had enabled Jersey tracing which outputs debugging info into the headers. It can be quite a lot of data, no surprise I got this error.